# Inner join with 'And' condition if exist else if not

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

I have table 'Images' I want to get the main image if exist, and if not, get the first row in the table. I use this:

```
SELECT Students.Id, Images.ImagePath
FROM Students INNER JOIN    
     Images 
     ON  Students.Id = Images.StudentId 
     AND (   (Images.IsMain = 1) 
          OR (Images.ImagePath = (
              SELECT TOP(1) ImagePath 
              FROM  Images 
              WHERE StudentId = Students.IdId)))
WHERE Students.Id = @StudentId
```

If there is no 'IsMain' in Images I get only one row, but if there is 'IsMain', I get the row twice.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ade7/1

Comment: "If there is no 'IsMain' in Images I get only one row, but if there is 'IsMain', I get the row twice." I want to get the "main" and if not exist, the first, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you were selecting the IsMain image *and* the first image.

The following code selects the first row, which will be the IsMain one if it exists, otherwise the top row.

```
SELECT Students.Id, Images.ImagePath
FROM Students INNER JOIN    
    Images 
    ON  Students.Id = Images.StudentId 
    AND Images.ImagePath = (
        SELECT TOP(1) ImagePath 
        FROM Images 
        WHERE StudentId = Students.Id
        ORDER BY IsMain DESC) -- This line forces the IsMain image to be the top image returned.
WHERE Students.Id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks RB. simple and smart.

Comment: @mosh No problems :) I just wish I knew why it got downvoted!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.*,
        CASE 
            WHEN b.StudentID IS NULL
            THEN c.ImagePath
            ELSE b.ImagePath
        END AS ImagePath
FROM    Students a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  StudentID, ImagePath
            FROM    Images
            WHERE   IsMain = 1
        ) b ON a.ID = b.StudentID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT StudentID, ImagePath,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  StudentID 
                                    ORDER BY ImagePath ASC) rn
            FROM    Images
        ) c ON c.rn = 1 AND
                a.ID = c.StudentID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with IsMain*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5e2d/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*without IsMain*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/243c3/1)

**UPDATE**

much more better one,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        c.ImagePath
FROM    Students a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT StudentID, ImagePath,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  StudentID 
                                    ORDER BY IsMain DESC) rn
            FROM    Images
        ) c ON  c.rn = 1 AND
                a.ID = c.StudentID
-- WHERE    a.ID = 1   -- remove this if you want for specific Student
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with IsMain*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5e2d/6)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*without IsMain*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/243c3/4)

If the student is **required to have atleast one record** on table `Images`, then change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
SELECT 
            S.Id, 
            COALESCE(MI.ImagePath, OI.ImagePath) ImagePath
FROM 
            Students S
    LEFT JOIN   
            Images MI 
                ON  S.Id = MI.StudentId AND MI.IsMain = 1
    INNER JOIN
            Images OI
            ( 
              SELECT TOP 1 ImagePath 
              FROM  Images 
              WHERE StudentId = Students.IdId
            )
    WHERE
        Students.Id = @StudentId
```

You ought to specify an order by in the sub query so you know which other image would be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

why all those queries are so complicated, am i missing something ? its as simple as getting first row

```
SELECT top (1) Students.Id, Images.ImagePath
FROM Students INNER JOIN    
     Images 
     ON  Students.Id = Images.StudentId 
WHERE Students.Id = 1
order by case when Images.IsMain = 1  then 1 else 0 end desc 
--order by Images.IsMain = 1
```

Comment: you query returns invalid result, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5e2d/2 . it should be `image2`

Comment: yes, this will work `:D` but for specific ID only. if you remove `WHERE Students.Id = 1` and the OP wants to get all records, this query will fail because of `TOP (1)`

Comment: in his query was Students.Id = @StudentId so i assume that he wanted image for a single user, not all of them